# Join values from array as keys to values from another array

Tags: groovy

From this JSON below:

```
{
   "query":{
      "ids":[
         95445875
      ],
      "group": "day",
      "dimensions":[
         "ym:s:date",
         "ym:s:lastSignUTMSource",
         "ym:s:lastSignUTMMedium",
         "ym:s:lastSignUTMCampaign",
         "ym:s:lastSignUTMContent",
         "ym:s:lastSignUTMTerm"
      ],
      "metrics":[
         "ym:s:goal315094773visits",
         "ym:s:goal318656867visits"
      ]
   },
   "data":[
      {
         "dimensions":[
            {
               "name":"2024-01-12"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka"
            },
            {
               "name":"SITE"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka_HR_nov23"
            },
            {
               "name":"button"
            },
            {
               "name":"click"
            }
         ],
         "metrics":[
            64.0,
            2.0
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensions":[
            {
               "name":"2024-01-13"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka"
            },
            {
               "name":"SITE"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka_HR_nov23"
            },
            {
               "name":"button"
            },
            {
               "name":"click"
            }
         ],
         "metrics":[
            13.0,
            0.0
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensions":[
            {
               "name":"2024-01-13"
            },
            {
               "name":"Yandex"
            },
            {
               "name":"SEM"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23"
            },
            {
               "name":"TGB"
            },
            {
               "name":"shop"
            }
         ],
         "metrics":[
            5.0,
            4.0
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensions":[
            {
               "name":"2024-01-12"
            },
            {
               "name":"Yandex"
            },
            {
               "name":"SEM"
            },
            {
               "name":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23"
            },
            {
               "name":"TGB"
            },
            {
               "name":"shop"
            }
         ],
         "metrics":[
            3.0,
            0.0
         ]
      }
   ],
   "total_rows":4
}
```

I expect to get this result:

```
[
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-12",
      "utm_source":"5ka",
      "utm_medium":"SITE",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_nov23",
      "utm_content":"button",
      "utm_term":"click",
      "goal_id":"315094773",
      "conversions":64.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-12",
      "utm_source":"5ka",
      "utm_medium":"SITE",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_nov23",
      "utm_content":"button",
      "utm_term":"click",
      "goal_id":"318656867",
      "conversions":2.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-13",
      "utm_source":"5ka",
      "utm_medium":"SITE",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_nov23",
      "utm_content":"button",
      "utm_term":"click",
      "goal_id":"315094773",
      "conversions":13.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-13",
      "utm_source":"5ka",
      "utm_medium":"SITE",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_nov23",
      "utm_content":"button",
      "utm_term":"click",
      "goal_id":"318656867",
      "conversions":0.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-12",
      "utm_source":"Yandex",
      "utm_medium":"SEM",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23",
      "utm_content":"TGB",
      "utm_term":"shop",
      "goal_id":"315094773",
      "conversions":5.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-12",
      "utm_source":"Yandex",
      "utm_medium":"SEM",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23",
      "utm_content":"TGB",
      "utm_term":"shop",
      "goal_id":"318656867",
      "conversions":4.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-13",
      "utm_source":"Yandex",
      "utm_medium":"SEM",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23",
      "utm_content":"TGB",
      "utm_term":"shop",
      "goal_id":"315094773",
      "conversions":3.0
   },
   {
      "counter_id":95445875,
      "date_of_visit":"2024-01-13",
      "utm_source":"Yandex",
      "utm_medium":"SEM",
      "utm_campaign":"5ka_HR_oct-dec'23",
      "utm_content":"TGB",
      "utm_term":"shop",
      "goal_id":"318656867",
      "conversions":0.0
   }
]
```

**Explanation**

From souce JSON I need:

- id from `query.ids` array and call new property `counter_id`
- compare and join values from array `query.dimensions` and values from array `data.dimensions`, but give them new names. Values from `query.dimensions` should be property names for values from `data.dimensions` (we need this to keep right order). After this I want to change these names: `ym:s:date` should be `date_of_visit`, `ym:s:lastSignUTMSource` should be `utm_source`, `ym:s:lastSignUTMMedium` to `utm_medium`, `ym:s:lastSignUTMCampaign` to `utm_campaign`, `ym:s:lastSignUTMContent` to `utm_content`, `ym:s:lastSignUTMTerm` to `utm_term`.
- compare and join values from `query.metrics` with values from array `data.metrics`. But each element from array `query.metrics`. f.e. `ym:s:goal315094773visits` should be written as `goal_id`: 315094773 (we need value between goal....visits). And value from `data.metrics` should be written as `conversions`.

I tried to write a Groovy script:

```
def inputJson = """
"""

def parseMetric(metric) {
    def matcher = metric =~ /ym:s:goal(\d+)visits/
    return ["goal_id": matcher[0][1].toLong(), "conversions": null]
}

def transform(json) {
    def query = json.query
    def data = json.data

    def result = []

    data.each { entry ->
        def dimensionsMap = [:]
        def metricsMap = [:]

        query.dimensions.eachWithIndex { dim, index ->
            def dimName = dim =~ /ym:s:(\S+)/
            dimensionsMap[dimName[0][1]] = entry.dimensions[index].name
        }

        query.metrics.eachWithIndex { metric, index ->
            def parsedMetric = parseMetric(metric)
            parsedMetric.conversions = entry.metrics[index]
            metricsMap.putAll(parsedMetric)
        }

        def entryResult = [
                "counter_id": query.ids[0],
                "date_of_visit": dimensionsMap['date'],
                "utm_source": dimensionsMap['lastSignUTMSource'],
                "utm_medium": dimensionsMap['lastSignUTMMedium'],
                "utm_campaign": dimensionsMap['lastSignUTMCampaign'],
                "utm_content": dimensionsMap['lastSignUTMContent'],
                "utm_term": dimensionsMap['lastSignUTMTerm'],
        ]

        entryResult.putAll(metricsMap)
        result.add(entryResult)
    }

    return result
}

def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def input = jsonSlurper.parseText(inputJson)

def output = transform(input)
def outputJson = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(output)
println outputJson
```

But I got result not I expected:

[image: result]

Seems like it grab only flast values `query.metrics`. So I only got result for `ym:s:goal315094773visits`. Second value inside arrays ignored. How to fix it?

Comment: it's not clear what's unexpected in current result. are you expecting to have a separate object in result for every item in ` "metrics":[64.0, 2.0]` ?

Comment: Your result contains 4 items - and you want 8; so you most likely want to make iterating the metric an inner loop.  And while you are at it, try to switch over to `collect`, `collectMany`, `collectEntries` instead of `each`+manipulate-state-somewhere.

Comment: @daggett, yes. But not only in [64.0, 2.0]. For all `metrics` array. For [13.0, 0.0] also, etc. It matches with values inside `query.metrics` array (they have same order). In my result there only values for `goal_id` = 318656867, but in `query.metrics` two values and I expect 8 items instead of 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your transform method like this:

```
def transform(json) {
    def query = json.query
    def dims = query.dimensions

    json.data.collectMany { entry ->
        def dimensionsMap = dims.indices.collectEntries { idx ->
            [(dims[idx] =~ /ym:s:(\S+)/)[0][1], entry.dimensions[idx].name]
        }

        def metrics = query.metrics.indexed().collect { idx, metric ->
            [goal_id: (metric =~ /ym:s:goal(\d+)visits/)[0][1].toLong(),
             conversions: entry.metrics[idx]]
        }

        metrics.collect {[
            counter_id: query.ids[0],
            date_of_visit: dimensionsMap['date'],
            utm_source: dimensionsMap['lastSignUTMSource'],
            utm_medium: dimensionsMap['lastSignUTMMedium'],
            utm_campaign: dimensionsMap['lastSignUTMCampaign'],
            utm_content: dimensionsMap['lastSignUTMContent'],
            utm_term: dimensionsMap['lastSignUTMTerm'],
            *:it
        ]}
    }
}
```

Plus delete your `parseMetric` method.